# Android libc in Htc Desire x throwing fatal signal SIGBUS and crashing

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc-desire, crashes

I have an HTC desire x(CID HTC_038) running a rooted stock Rom,my problem is that the phone crashes reboots randomly by throwing fatal signal 7 SIGBUS at various addresses. I have the following logcat outputs and I cannot see any software faults that could lead to this problem:

**Logcat output 1**

```
D/Socket_Alarm( 6570): HTCSocketMonitorImpl::HTCSocketMonitorImpl
D/LocationManagerService(  224): add listener to CarGpsProvider to provide NMEA
V/LocationManagerService(  224): requestLocationUpdates
V/LocationManagerService(  224): _requestLocationUpdates: listener = Receiver{40f323c8 Listener android.os.BinderProxy@41570118}mUpdateRecords: {}
V/LocationManagerService(  224): _requestLocationUpdates: provider = passive listener = Receiver{40f323c8 Listener android.os.BinderProxy@41570118}mUpdateRecords: {passive=UpdateRecord{413aba28 mProvider: passive mUid: 10049}}
D/WifiService(  224): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationLocator type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@413e8640}
D/WifiService(  224): updateWifiState(): enable and start wifi
D/WifiStateMachine(  224): [DriverStartedState] CMD_START_DRIVER
D/WifiStateMachine(  224): setWifiEnabled: true
I/PackageManager(  224):  setEnabledSetting(), pkgName=com.google.android.apps.maps, clsName=com.google.android.maps.driveabout.app.DestinationActivity, state=1, flag=1, pid=5948, uid=10049
W/wpa_supplicant(  287): wlan0: [HTC] wpa_supplicant_event():2261- Got an original EVENT_SCAN_RESULTS
I/global  ( 6570): call createSocket() return a new socket.
D/WifiStateMachine(  224): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -56
W/System  ( 6570): Error writing session data for www.google.com to /data/data/com.google.android.apps.maps/app_sslcache/www.google.com.443.
F/libc    ( 6570): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x4d34ecf9 (code=2)
D/GpsLocationProvider(  224): GPS status listener died
D/CarGpsProvider(  224): GPS Mock status listener died
D/LocationManagerService(  224): [LPS] In removeUpdatesLocked.p.setMinTime:
W/ContentService(  224): binderDied() at ObserverNode
D/WifiStateMachine(  224): [DriverStartedState] CMD_START_DRIVER
V/LocationManagerService(  224): Location listener died
V/LocationManagerService(  224): _removeUpdates: listener = Receiver{40f323c8 Listener android.os.BinderProxy@41570118}mUpdateRecords: {passive=UpdateRecord{413aba28 mProvider: passive mUid: 10049}}
D/WifiService(  224): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationLocator type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@413e8640}
D/WifiService(  224): updateWifiState(): enable and start wifi
D/WifiStateMachine(  224): setWifiEnabled: true
I/ActivityManager(  224): Process com.google.android.apps.maps:NetworkLocationService (pid 6570) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  224): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.server.NetworkLocationService in 5000ms
D/Zygote  (  134): Process 6570 terminated by signal (7)
D/WifiStateMachine(  224): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -55
I/ActivityManager(  224): Start proc com.google.android.apps.maps:NetworkLocationService for service com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.location.internal.server.NetworkLocationService: pid=6608 uid=10049 gids={3003, 1015}
D/Socket_Alarm( 6608): registerHTCSocketMonitorCallBack
D/Socket_Alarm( 6608): set mSocketMonitor
D/Socket_Alarm( 6608): HTCSocketMonitorImpl::HTCSocketMonitorImpl
D/WifiStateMachine(  224): fetchRssiAndLinkSpeedNative RSSI = -54
D/LocationManagerService(  224): add listener to CarGpsProvider to provide NMEA
V/LocationManagerService(  224): requestLocationUpdates
V/LocationManagerService(  224): _requestLocationUpdates: listener = Receiver{413db688 Listener android.os.BinderProxy@415effa8}mUpdateRecords: {}
V/LocationManagerService(  224): _requestLocationUpdates: provider = passive listener = Receiver{413db688 Listener android.os.BinderProxy@415effa8}mUpdateRecords: {passive=UpdateRecord{413bb580 mProvider: passive mUid: 10049}}
I/PackageManager(  224):  setEnabledSetting(), pkgName=com.google.android.apps.maps, clsName=com.google.android.maps.driveabout.app.DestinationActivity, state=1, flag=1, pid=5948, uid=10049
D/WifiService(  224): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NetworkLocationLocator type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@41716128}
D/WifiService(  224): updateWifiState(): enable and start wifi
D/WifiStateMachine(  224): [DriverStartedState] CMD_START_DRIVER
D/WifiStateMachine(  224): setWifiEnabled: true
F/libc    (  439): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x5226616e (code=2)
W/ContentService(  224): binderDied() at ObserverNode
W/ContentService(  224): binderDied() at ObserverNode
W/ContentService(  224): binderDied() at ObserverNode
W/ContentService(  224): binderDied() at ObserverNode
W/ContentService(  224): binderDied() at ObserverNode
W/ContentService(  224): binderDied() at ObserverNode
D/Process (  224): killProcessQuiet, pid=623
W/AudioFlinger(  136): AudioFlinger::NotificationClient::binderDied() died
I/ActivityManager(  224): Process com.android.phone (pid 439) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  224): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.phone/.BluetoothHeadsetService in 1250ms
W/ActivityManager(  224): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.stk/.StkAppService in 11250ms
W/ActivityManager(  224): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.phone/.NetworkQueryService in 21250ms
I/ActivityManager(  224): Kill android.process.acore (pid 623): provider com.android.phone.IccProvider in dying process com.android.phone
I/ActivityThread(  623): Removing dead content provider: icc
D/Zygote  (  134): Process 439 terminated by signal (7)
F/libc    (  224): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x4dc1bd31 (code=2)
W/AudioFlinger(  136): power manager service died !!!
W/AudioFlinger(  136): AudioFlinger::NotificationClient::binderDied() died
W/AudioFlinger(  136): session id 16 not found for pid 136
W/Sensors ( 3824): sensorservice died [0x7464c0]
I/ActivityThread( 4415): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread(  303): Removing dead content provider: settings
E/OMXCodec(  136): wrong state to free OMXCodec 1
I/ActivityThread( 4374): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread( 1934): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread( 2496): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread(  999): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread(  623): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread(  450): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread( 4429): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread( 3699): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread( 5948): Removing dead content provider: settings
W/Sensors ( 6608): sensorservice died [0x78c870]
I/ActivityThread(  417): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread( 4520): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread( 6608): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread( 5692): Removing dead content provider: settings
I/ActivityThread(  503): Removing dead content provider: settings
E/SurfaceTexture(  133): [StatusBar] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
E/SurfaceTextureClient(  303): dequeueBuffer failed (No such device)
F/libc    (  303): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x4d3a518b (code=2)
W/wpa_supplicant(  287): wlan0: [HTC] wpa_supplicant_event():2261- Got an original EVENT_SCAN_RESULTS
D/Zygote  (  134): Process 303 terminated by signal (7)
E/SurfaceTexture(  133): [com.htc.music/com.htc.music.HtcMusic] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
E/SurfaceTextureClient( 4415): dequeueBuffer failed (No such device)
F/libc    (  139): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x0000973c (code=2)
F/libc    ( 4415): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x4d3a518b (code=2)
W/JavaBinder( 2944): BinderProxy is being destroyed but the application did not call unlinkToDeath to unlink all of its death recipients beforehand.  Releasing leaked death recipient: android.database.CursorToBulkCursorAdaptor
D/Zygote  (  134): Process 4415 terminated by signal (7)
F/libc    (  138): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x400c4222 (code=2)
D/Zygote  (  134): Process 224 terminated by signal (7)
I/Zygote  (  134): Exit zygote because system server (224) has terminated
F/libc    (  144): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x0000af4c (code=2)
```

**Locat output 2**

```
E/SurfaceTexture(  134): [StatusBar] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
E/SurfaceTextureClient(  378): dequeueBuffer failed (No such device)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378): IllegalArgumentException locking surface
E/ViewRootImpl(  378): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:76)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2158)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1810)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2700)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/ViewRootImpl(  378):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/InputQueue-JNI(  378): channel '413d4c70 StatusBar (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputQueue-JNI(  378): channel '413d5be0 NavigationBar (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputQueue-JNI(  378): channel '413517f0 TrackingView (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputQueue-JNI(  378): channel '41630278 RecentsPanel (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputQueue-JNI(  378): channel '413556a8 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputQueue-JNI(  496): channel '41287c10 com.htc.launcher/com.htc.launcher.Launcher (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputQueue-JNI(  378): channel '412ebea8 StatusBarExpanded (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
D/Zygote  (  135): Process 267 terminated by signal (7)
I/Zygote  (  135): Exit zygote because system server (267) has terminated
F/libc    ( 3472): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x0000efe0 (code=2)
```

I cannot figure out what is going wrong. can anybody help me?
The full logcat can be found [in this link](https://drive.google.com/?usp=chrome_app#folders/0BztnhKc9Y8g6R2ZyVklGS1JEUUU).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the issue and resolved it!, the error was in the firmware of the device(especially in the radio,don't ask me how did it got the error, cz i've no idea). The solution is to download the OTA update and install it in the device. if the OTA update is not able to install to the system because you have a custom recovery, goto cache\ and find the OTA update package like `OTA_PROTO_U_JB_45A_S_hTC_Asia_India_2.22.720.6-1.18.720.3_release_316889ltmnu8ffxfy8672r.zip` open it with WInzip/Winrar/7zip and extract the  `firmware.zip` to a folder. This archive contain the firmware files like `radio.img,recovery.img,boot.img,hboot` etc. now we are going to flash the file to the device if you are on an unlocked bootloader

### Re-lock the bootloader

1.reboot the device to bootloader(goto cmd>type `adb reboot-bootloader`)

2.type `fastboot oem lock`

### Flash the `firmware.zip`

1.type `fastboot oem rebootRUU`

1. `cd` to the directory where the `firmware.zip` is located.

3.type `fastboot flash zip firmware.zip`

now the  firmware is updated and it will be visible in the bootloader menu,use the HTC provided method for unlocking the bootloader

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the logcat, `libc` does not like it at all, coincidentally it does look like the wifi triggering it?

But this what caught my eye though:

```
> W/System  ( 6570): Error writing session data for www.google.com to
> /data/data/com.google.android.apps.maps/app_sslcache/www.google.com.443.
> F/libc    ( 6570): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x4d34ecf9 (code=2)
```

- Are you running out of space on the `/data` partition?

The OMXCodec, which is related to the graphics driver, should not be crashing like that at all:

> `E/OMXCodec(  136): wrong state to free OMXCodec 1`

Questions:

- Try disabling the wifi completely, and check for stability with it turned off, any differences?
- When did the problem appear? Was it after you installed a last app recently?
- Are you running some app that requires root and modifies the system - such as Xposed module running?
- What version of Android are you referring to?
- Is it overclocked?

These are the questions you need to work out and investigate.

Last resort - try a factory reset or wipe cache/data from recovery (You will lose root!)

Comment: I have tried all the available options before posting it to this site - disabled wifi,turned on offline mode,disabled apps,wiped and tried roms,kernels and recoveries used many CPU governors tried tools like Kernel tuner and nothing seems to be a help so far.from your answer i think there maybe some corruption in the /data partition i'll try to re-format the /data and other partitions and see if it will help,Thanks for the reply anyway